# Error while using ord() in reduce function in Python

Tags: python, functional-programming

I have the following reduce function in python which is supposed to return the sum of the ASCII values of all the characters in the string. For example for the string "BOY" the reduce function should return 234.

```
reduce(lambda x,y:ord(x)+ord(y),list("BOY"))
```

But im getting the following error:

```
TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found
```

What is the problem with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
reduce(lambda x,y:ord(x)+ord(y),list("BOY"))
```

Think about how this reduces:

```
'B' 'O' 'Y'
145 'Y'
```

What is `ord(145) + ord('Y')`? Its an error.

Others have suggested:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x + ord(y), "BOY", 0)
```

Which reduces like:

```
0 'B' 'O' 'Y'
66 'O' 'Y'
145 'Y'
234
```

I'd recommend

```
sum(map(ord, "BOY"))
```

Comment: @user1276174 As a general note when using reduce, watch for the cases when your function produces a result of a different type than the things stored in the collection. In that case you must provide an initial value, and the function needs to take one argument that is the same type as the result it produces and one argument that comes from the collection.

Answer (score 2):

This should be

```
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x + ord(y), "BOY", 0)
234
```

The left operand `x` of the lambda function will always be the result of the previous invocation of the function, so it's an integer.  Wee need to provide a start value `0`, but it's not necessary to convert the string to a list -- the string is iterable itself.

You would have avoided this problem if you would have followed [Guido's recommendation to write the accumulation loop explicitly](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196):

```
result = 0:
for x in "BOY":
    result += ord(x)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This works, but could you please explain why this works and the error in my code ?.Thanks

Comment: @user1276174: I added some explanations.

Comment: +1 for a good explanation and indicating Guido's preference, but I think Roman's approach is better in this specific case.

Answer (score 2):

Why not `sum(map(ord, "BOY"))` ?